# How to populate a 2D array with mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, web, mongoose, multidimensional-array

## I am tring to populate an array that containes other arrays of objects

> i made this nested loops to create the path but it seems like it's not working the objects in 'sub' (the 2d >array) are still just ids

```
const arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < req.user.sub.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < req.user.sub[i].length; j++) {
        arr.push(`sub.${i}.${j}`)
    }
}
const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).populate(arr.join(' '))
console.log(user.sub)
```

## The 2D array shema part

```
sub: [
        [
            {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Subject",
            }
        ]
    ]
```

> help me please!

## The output

```
[
  [ new ObjectId("64049bc6c94f9de6cee71121") ],
  [ new ObjectId("64049c01bf006841ace18ee0") ],
  [ new ObjectId("64049c74369bcb9f76788aa6") ],
]
```

## what i am expecting

```
[
  [ {name:...,coff:...}, {name:...,coff:...}],
  [ {name:...,coff:...}, {name:...,coff:...}],
  [ {name:...,coff:...}, {name:...,coff:...}]
]
```